# Let $X:\Omega \rightarrow R_+$ be a non negative random variable. Does $E[X] < \infty$ implies $P(X<\infty) = 1$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying this question and at the moment, I am stuck at $P(x=\infty) = E[1_{\{X=\infty\}}]$.

I think I need to somehow show $P(x=\infty) = 0$ and through $E[X] < \infty$ but not sure how to connect the dots

Answer (score 0):

I would say that by definition of $X : \Omega \to R_{+}$, $X$ is finite on $\Omega$, hence also almost surely finite.

If you allow $X$ to take $\infty$ as a value, then you can argue via the following contradiction.

Suppose $P(X < \infty) < 1$, then there exists a measurable set $A \subset \Omega$ such that $X$ constrained on $A$ is equal to $\infty$. Since $ X \geq 0$ and $P(A) > 0$, we have

$$E[X] \geq E[X 1_{A}] = \infty * P(A) = \infty.$$